# MySQL query column name substring

Tags: mysql, sql, select, substring, substr

Is it possible to combine the use of back ticks ` with the substr() function? I have column names with hyphens '-' which require the use of backticks to query but seems like I cannot do something like:

```
  SELECT substr(`abc-def-ghi`,1,5) FROM tableName
```

Where the aim is to select all rows from columns starting with abc-d. Unfortunately changing/removing the hyphens is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot do what you want with a simple SQL statement.  When you use `abc-def-ghi`, you get the *value* of the column, not the *name*.

A SQL `SELECT` statement returns a fixed set of columns with a fixed set of names,  You cannot select names that way.

If you want to do something like this, then you would need to use dynamic SQL (`prepare` and `exec`).  However, I suspect that you might have a poor data model.  You might want to ask another question, show the table layout, and ask if that is a reasonable data structure for what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Gordon. I guess I have to make "changing column names" an option after all. My model is indeed not optimal since I'm aware it would be better to query the rows than the columns, however I'm constrained by the limit on the number of columns; hence had to set the higher dimension as the rows (higher limit) and the other dimension as columns.