# Is there a way for me to get the first 3 letters of a column's name on sql?

Tags: mysql, sql

I tried looking everywhere but the only results id get is how to get the first 3 letters of a column's content, but that's not what I want. To make my point more clear I'll give an example: if there's a column called **Employee_name** and it had **josh** and **Emily** in it, I want to be able to get the first 3 letters of its name, which in this case would be **Emp**

Comment: do you need first 3 letters from column name or from the data in column. If only from column name is required then you have posted the content .

Comment: Would that help?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165195/mysql-query-to-get-column-names

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL query column name substring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37655486/mysql-query-column-name-substring)

Comment: I need the first 3 letters from the column's name. again, if the column name is Employee I want to get Emp, I don't really care what data it holds. @AmitVerma

Comment: yes, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you both SO much! @ekochergin

Comment: @Zachary ^ you too

Answer (score 2):

Maybe somethin like this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(`COLUMN_NAME`, 1, 3) AS col
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='your_db_name' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='your_table_name';
```